# The AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation can not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

The method:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:nil]
```

does not work for resuming background music.
My app audio session category is `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`.

Who knows what's going on？